# update IFile content in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a File that I would like to update based on some user menu selection.
My code gets the IFile 
if it does not exist it's been created (with the user's content),and if it exists it should be updated. 
My current code is:

```
    String userString= "original String"; //This will be set by the user
    byte[] bytes = userString.getBytes();
    InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    try {
        if( !file.exists()){
            file.create(source, IResource.NONE, null);
        }
        else{
            InputStream content = file.getContents();
            //TODO augment content
            file.setContents(content, 1, null);
        }

    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        IDE.openEditor(page, file);
```

My problem is that even though I get the original content and set the file's content, I am getting an empty file upon update , i.e., the entire content is being deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code just sets the file's contents to the existing contents if the file already exists. However I would guess this may well end up truncating the file because you are reading and writing the file at the same time. What do you actually want to do if the file already exists?

Comment: Hey. sorry if my post was not clear but I have a //TODO augment content
The idea that based on user input, I will get the current file content + add the users input to the current existing content, and set the file with the new content.

Since I want to avoid any sync problems, it seems that the best thing to do is to take the content, change it and re-set it .

But when I do setContents, I am getting an empty file

Comment: Did you call `content.close()` after finish reading?

Comment: You need to show us the actual code you are using to get the contents because what you have currently shown us makes no sense and doesn't show what the problem might be.

Comment: @greg-499, say that I want to add "added" to the current content of the file
isn't  '''            InputStream content = file.getContents();
                       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                       IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, encoding);
                       String theString = writer.toString();
                       theString = theString + "  added"
                      byte[] bytes = theString.getBytes();
                     InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                        file.setContents(source, 1, null);'''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version of the code in your comment works for me:

```
InputStream inputStream = file.getContents();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

// Copy to string, use the file's encoding
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, file.getCharset());

// Done with input
inputStream.close();

String theString = writer.toString();

theString = theString + " added";

// Get bytes using the file's encoding
byte[] bytes = theString.getBytes(file.getCharset());

InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

file.setContents(source, IResource.FORCE, null);
```

Note the close of the original input stream and the use of `file.getCharset()` to use the correct encoding.

Comment: I was missing the inputStream.close();